# guive html to keyframe css

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have follow function:

```
      $.keyframe.define([{
          name: 'playSlide',
          tMin : {'margin-left': "0"},
          tMax : {'margin-left': "0"},
      }]);
```

But i need make it:

```
      $.keyframe.define([{
          name: 'playSlide',              
          content: variable
      }]);
```

This variable is text

```
text = "'0%' : { 'margin-left':'-0%'},";
text += "'25%' : { 'margin-left':'-0%'},";
text += "'30%' : { 'margin-left':'-100%'},";
text += "'50%' :{ 'margin-left':'-100%'},";
text += "'55%' : { 'margin-left':'-200%'},";
text += "'75%' : { 'margin-left':'-200%'},";
text += "'80%' : { 'margin-left':'-300%'},";
text += "'100%' : { 'margin-left':'-300%'}";
```

Is it possible?

Maybe of other form:

```
$("<style> @keyframes playSlide").html(text2);
```

Ou maybe:

```
   $("animation playSlide").html(text2);
```

with: text2 variable below

```
text2 = "0% : { margin-left:-0%},";
text2 += "25% : { margin-left:-0%},";
text2 += "30% : { margin-left:-100%},";
text2 += "50% :{ margin-left:-100%},";
text2 += "55% : { margin-left:-200%},";
text2 += "75% : { margin-left:-200%},";
text2 += "80% : { margin-left:-300%},";
text2 += "100% : { margin-left:-300%}";
```

I can not do it

Nothing works

Comment: Why aren't you just putting this into a stylesheet?

Comment: 'Cause it not be static. Its will depends of number of images.

Comment: It looks like you're using a plugin, [based on the documentation](https://github.com/Keyframes/jQuery.Keyframes#usage), your implementation is not correct at all and what you're trying to do would not be possible without modifying the plugin.

Comment: i am making this plugin. I onli need do it.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Read up on the plugin's documentation to learn how to configure it.

Comment: please, review the question on more time and you will see that the question is clear yes. I only want insert into @keyframe css, styles that it variable conform situation

Comment: It might be more simple for you if you just used js to do the animation instead of trying to frankenstein together some css. Also, if my guess is correct and you're doing some sort of slideshow, just look up a tutorial on how to do it the right way.

Comment: then there is not a way to do it that i want? fill a css keyframe dynamically

Comment: You can create a CSS keyframe dynamically, just not using the plugin you are using. It wasn't built to work like that.

Comment: this plugin i some am doing it. Cause this is that want put it to work